# Spring CORS policy error on WebSocket Application

Tags: spring, websocket, cors

in my Spring boot web application, a have a Spring **CORS policy error** on **WebSocket** Application even configuring WebMvcConfigure:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080","origin2","origin3");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for not being clear. In a Spring Boot web application, the CORS rules are set in WebMvcConfigurer object, but in the specific case, I have a WebSocket application where the CORS set must be in WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer object as shown below.

Answer (score -1):

In this case we need configure CORS in **registerStompEndpoints** on **WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer** and not **WebMvcConfigurer**.

The sulution is:

```
...
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")
                .setAllowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:8080",
                        "origin2",
                        "origin3"
                )
                .withSockJS();
    }
```